# Is it possible to use multiple queues for the same service while using nameko?

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, microservices, nameko

I have a flask+nameko setup.
When there is a request coming in, I want to use different queues based on a parameter in the request body.
Is it possible to do so ?